# Honda Interceptor 1987 Spark Plugs getting carbon fouled within seconds. Vehicle idling louder than usual

Tags: engine, sparkplugs, carbon

I recently installed a new engine on my Interceptor. After riding for about half an hour the bike petered out. I left in in the garage for about 7 months before installing new spark plugs. This got it running again, but it idles extremely loud, as if I was cranking the throttle all the way, and the plugs become carbon fouled within seconds. I tried to start the bike up the next day and it wouldn't work until I'd put a fresh set of plugs in it. What might I want to inspect? Is it safe to keep a bike running if it's idling so loudly?

Comment: Have you ridden it since you got it running again? How's the power? I wonder if the timing jumped.

Comment: I haven't, it runs so loud that I worry it will break. I've only run it for periods of less than 10 seconds and in that time the sparkplugs start to blacken

Comment: "gunked" how about a picture of the spark plug?

Comment: @Moab this is a picture of a plug that was only in for a few seconds, the insulator tip, once white, is already becoming greyed: https://ibb.co/vj2chBm

Comment: @GriffinHines Link is broken

Comment: Sorry, this one should work: https://ibb.co/vJ2chBm

Comment: Who supplied this new engine? Junk yard?

Comment: @Tony I got it off Ebay, mileage is fairly low but it could have problems as far as I know.

Comment: ECU may have info you need if you can get a portable analyzer.  Check all vacuum hoses for leaks